# torch.cuda.is_availabe() continuously returns False

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm currently in a lab at the school I'm at and we use GPU servers for our tasks. I've tried running the `torch.cuda.is_available()` function but it continuously returns False despite me having tried this and that.

By "this and that" I specifically mean that I've tried installing and reinstalling PyTorch, I've ensured that CUDA is indeed available by running the `nvidia-smi` command, I've also checked the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environmental variable and made sure that it's correctly assigned.

The GPU devices are either `0` or `1`, and my environmental variable is currently set to `1`.

Currently the specs that I have are:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

CUDA: 9.0176

Python: 3.7.0

cuDNN: 9.0-v7.0.5

Nvidia driver: 384.81

Has anyone experienced this issue? If so, how was it solved?

**EDIT**

I've currently re-installed PyTorch from the Github source as suggested [PyTorch - Get Started - Building From Source](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#linux-from-source), and it's fixed my issue. However, it would still be greatly helpful to me and the community in general if anyone could provide some insight onto why such problems occur in the first place. Thank you.

**EDIT 2**

As @kHarshit suggested in the comments, I ran `collect_env.py` located in `pytorch/torch/utils/` and got the following output:

```
Collecting Environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.3.0a0+6a4ca9a
is debug build: No
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 9.0.176

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
GCC version: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
CMake version: version 3.14.0

Python version: 3.7
Is CUDA available: No
CUDA runtime version: 9.0.176
GPU models and configuration:
GPU 0: TITAN Xp
GPU 1: TITAN Xp

Nvidia driver version: 384.81
cuDNN version: Could not collect

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.17.2
[pip3] numpydoc=0.8.0
[pip3] torch=1.3.0a0+6a4ca9a
[pip3] torch-cluster=1.4.4
[pip3] torch-geometric=1.3.1
[pip3] torch-scatter==1.3.1
[pip3] torch-sparse==0.4.0
[pip3] torch-spline-conv==1.1.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.4.0
[conda] blas                    1.0                    mkl
[conda] mkl                     2019.4                 243
[conda] mkl-include             2019.4                 243
[conda] mkl-service             2.3.0       py37he904b0f_0
[conda] mkl_fft                 1.0.14      py37ha843d7b_0
[conda] mkl_random              1.1.0       py37hd6b4f25_0
[conda] torch                   1.2.0               pypi_0     pypi
[conda] torch-cluster           1.4.4               pypi_0     pypi
[conda] torch-geometric         1.3.1               pypi_0     pypi
[conda] torch-scatter           1.3.1               pypi_0     pypi
[conda] torch-sparse            0.4.0               pypi_0     pypi
[conda] torch-spline-conv       1.1.0               pypi_0     pypi
[conda] torchvision             0.4.0               pypi_0     pypi
```

I'm not too familiar with this and am not sure if there is any information indicative of a potential problem. If there is, would anyone be kind enough to point it out? Thanks.

Comment: Check the output of [collect_env.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py), it'll give you more info.

Comment: Check how many nvidia drivers you have installed , I had the same problem and the cause was that I had two nvidia drivers installed so when I removed a one then reinstalled Pytorch it worked